# Access the USGS library for hyperspectral imagery (how to read the library in MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing

I want to download a spectral library that contains a lot of spectral signatures of different minerals in Hyperspectral imagery.

The spectral library is located in this website [Click here!](http://speclab.cr.usgs.gov/spectral.lib04/spectral-lib04.html)

I downloaded the **splib04a - ftp Compressed Binary** that contains all the spectrums. When I am writing in MATLAB `importdata('splib04a')`, I only get a structure of size `1 x 1` and so I am not able to read the spectral library correctly.

Kindly, do you know how to read this spectral library in MATLAB in order to access every signature in it? Does someone worked on this before?

Any help will be very appreciated!

Comment: The splib04a.Z file is in a format that is specified on the USGS website (the link right under the download). Since MATLAB doesn't know about this format you would need to find a 3rd party parser or write your own.

Comment: why did you remove your answer?